# Identify game with 'Cataclysm cards and Sin cards' based on game end rules

Tags: identify-this-game

A friend has found some rules to a game he printed off several years ago and had in a box that wasn't the game.  The pages also seem to be just a print off of 'Advanced rules'.  Unfortunately the game doesn't have the game title on it (to our knowledge at least).   I don't want to type all the rules out but there are references to Cataclysm cards and Sin cards.    The came rules also have references to an 'Unnamed player', Corrupted Hero, completing quest cards and manning buildings.

I'm hoping that typing game end rules will help identify it best.

> The game ends when one of three things happens:
>
> 1) When the players collect all 7 pieces of armor, and one of them has at least 30 points of might.  That player is the winner.  If several players have more than 30 might point, the player with the most points in the winner.
>
> 2) When the last, 14th Cataclysm is played, the present turn is played until the end of the regrouping phase.  If non of the players acheived the connditions mentioned in 1), the game ends with the defeat of the players and a victory for the Unnames (and evil players if using advanced rules)
>
> 3) The players closed the last of the portals, The player who contributed most to the closing of portals (the board hold a majority of his tokens) is declared the winner.  In case of a tie, the winner is the player with the most might points.

Hopefully this enough for someone to recognise it without typing all the rules out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could google the game: Its called "7".

Googling the first sentence of the second paragraph, I found the rule book. It does, for some strange reason, not contain the game name written anywhere. (The pdf was called "7_Rulebook_english.pdf", but I did not get that hint ;) )

However, at the end of the rules, it states the game designer, and googling him led me to boardgamegeek.

So, here you go:
https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/53376/7
https://tesera.ru/images/items/69366/7_Rulebook_English.pdf

Edit: Okay, the rulebook starts with the logo of the game, that includes a 7. I just did not get that thats the game name :D

Comment: thanks for this.  We did try googling various terms from the game but didn't find anything and didn't try the specific line you did.  Thanks for help.